# IronPython init() being called by C# Operations.InvokeMember?

Tags: c#, python, ironpython

So basically I've created a Python object, and I want to call one of its functions, as below.

```
public static dynamic ExecuteClassFunction(string filePath, OldInstance pythonObject, string functionName, dynamic[] arguments)
{
    s_ScriptScope = s_PythonEngine.ExecuteFile(filePath);
    return s_PythonEngine.Operations.InvokeMember(pythonObject, functionName, arguments);
}
```

However, I get the error "init() takes exactly 1 argument (3 given)". Why is it calling init(), even though I have already initialised the object previously?

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, I found out that I was calling a constructor elsewhere and passing values into it when I shouldn't have.